# How to use ARRAYFORMULA to classify the Action in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

[image]

Hi everyone,

I'm using `ARRAYFORMULA` to summarized the Action in column A. The classification should be:

1. `Enter` and `Re-enter` = `Entry order`
2. `Exit` = `Other`

Based on my formula in cell B2, seems like I'm not able to use `ARRAYFORMULA` in this case because the output are all `Entry order`. Instead of applying formula to each cell in column B, how should I modify my formula so that the `ARRAYFORMULA` work perfectly?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"OR" can't be iterated over an array. Instead try

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), if( (A2:A="Enter")+(A2:A="Re-enter"), "Entry order", "Other"),))
```